# Pass variable to resource class in Jersey

Tags: java, resources, jersey

I'm trying to use a variable that is passed through command line arguments to the main function and that should be somehow visible inside a resource class in jersey.

My main function:

```
public class MyApp extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApp(String directory) {

        // I would like the MyResource.class to have access to the 
        // variable that is passed in the main function below, 
        // which is the directory variable
        register(MyResurce.class);
    }

    public void startHttpServer(int port) { ... }

    // args[0]: a port to start a HTTP server
    // args[1]: a string that is CONSTANT and UNIQUE throughout the 
    // full execution of the app, and the MyResource.class resource        
    // should be able to read it. How can I pass this variable to the resource?
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
            final MyApp app = new MyApp(args[1]);
            int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            app.startHttpServer(port);
    }
}
```

The resource class has nothing special, only @GET, @DELETE and @POST methods. What should I do so that the variable given in args[1] is visible not only to the MyResource.class but to all resources registered?

Comment: Couldn't you get the `ResourceConfig` properties and add the `directory` to the properties' map?

Comment: @aribeiro good idea, and how can I access the `ResourceConfig` properties in a resource class?

Comment: nice question! After reading some things I didn't find a way to do  it. **But**, there's another way I think... Do you need your directory to be passed as an argument?

Comment: I guess I can read the path in a config file, then again the path to the config file would need to be provided, so I guess it's the same thing right?

Comment: Well, you can solve you problem by injecting the `JAX-RS Application` itself. Check my answer in order to see how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inject, in your resource class, the `JAX-RS` application you can access the properties `Map`:

```
@Path(...)
public class MyResource {

    @Context
    private Application app;

    @GET
    @Path(...)
    public String someMethod() {
        String directory = app.getProperties().get("directory");
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, your main class would be like this:

```
public class MyApp extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApp(String directory) {
        register(MyResource.class);

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("directory", directory);
        setProperties(properties);
    }

    public void startHttpServer(int port) { ... }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        final MyApp app = new MyApp(args[1]);
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        app.startHttpServer(port);
    }
}
```

You can do the above since `ResourceConfig` extends `Application`.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, however I'm getting an error when trying this:
```java
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.put(Collections.java:1457)
 at app.RiskOntologiesApp.<init>(MyApp.java:48)
 at app.RiskOntologiesApp.main(MyApp.java:92)
```


It's breaking in the line `getProperties().put("directory", directory)`